# How to transition to top of the page with swup js

Tags: javascript, swup

Using Swup JS I achieved a nice transition effect which works fine except for one issue.

If I scroll down to a certain point on page "A", hit the url to transition to page "B", I am not transitioned to the very top of page "B" but instead the scroll point is the same or close.

How can I make swup js not remember the scroll position and transition me to the top of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const options = {
    animationSelector: '[class*="transition-fade"]',
    animateHistoryBrowsing: true,
    plugins: [

        new SwupScrollPlugin({
            animateScroll: false
        })
    ]
};

const swup = new Swup(options);

let scrollValues = {};

swup.on('clickLink', () => {
    scrollValues[window.location.href] = window.scrollY;
});

swup.on('popState', () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollValues[window.location.href]);
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me firs stay that I am a still a bit of a noob when it comes to Javascript, so excuse my ignorance.

However, I did find a solution (probably a crude one).

I have read the documentation on https://swup.js.org/events and only some of it made sense to me.
So I used the bits that made sense to formulate this solution.
This is how I tackled it;
First, I used one of the swup.on events to trigger the whole thing.

```
swup.on('animationInStart', scrollToPlace); // When the incoming animation is starting we call the scroll function
```

Then, I created a variable that was assigned to the assigned to the page wrapper (this is the parent of the swup container that had an ‘id’ of swup);

```
let pageWrapper = document.querySelector(".page-wrapper");
```

Then, I create a blank div of where I wanted the page to scroll to, like this;

```
<div id="need-to-scroll-here" class="anchor"></div>
```

Then I created a mini function that assigned the ‘scroll-to’ element to a variable, created a variable that got the position of said element from the ‘getPosition’ function, then told the ‘pageWrapper’ (defined above) to scroll to the position I had just obtained.

```
    function scrollToPlace(){ 
        var myElement = document.querySelector("#need-to-scroll-here"); // Here is the element that we want to scroll to 
        var position = getPosition(myElement);     
        pageWrapper.scrollTo(0, position.y)
```

}

I used a function that locates in pixels the location of that div (referred to above);

```
function getPosition(el) {
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

while (el) {
if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
    // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
    var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
    yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
} else {
    // for all other non-BODY elements
    xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
    yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
}

el = el.offsetParent;
}
return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
};
```

}

As I said, the documentation still doesn’t make much sense to me, because in most instances, it doesn’t demonstrate the syntax of the code in contextually relevant examples, which is the particular way I learn.
I hope that this can be of some use to someone, and if there is a better way of doing it, then please chip in.
Hopefully, this will improve my score of minus 4, all because I asked a ‘stupid question’ I asked nine years ago when I knew even less about coding as I do now which has resulteed in me being banned from asking and answering any questions!